# XCTest failed with all green checks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm writing objective-c code that micmic account transactions. And I'm using XCTest framework to test my code. Although I have all green checks without single red cross, Xcode prompts that the test failed. I couldn't find what causing this so I comment out all my test code except this assertion line which always evaluates to true - "XCTAssertEqual(1, 1, @"Test Failed: Result isn't equal to expected value"). Even after that, the test still failed. Here's the output

> Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-02-05 02:07:24 +0000 
>   Test Suite 'Test.xctest' started at 2014-02-05 02:07:24 +0000 
>   Test Suite 'Test' started at 2014-02-05 02:07:24 +0000 
>   Test Case '-[Test testDeposit]' started. 
>   Test Case '-[Test testDeposit]' passed (0.000 seconds). 
>   Test Case '-[Test testExample]' started. 
>   Test Case '-[Test testExample]' passed (0.000 seconds). 
>   Test Suite 'Test' finished at 2014-02-05 02:07:24 +0000. 
>   Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds 
>   Test Suite 'Test.xctest' finished at 2014-02-05 02:07:24 +0000. 
>   Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds 
>   Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2014-02-05 02:07:24 +0000. 
>   Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.002) seconds 
>   Program ended with exit code: 0

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Where is the part that says it failed?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Xcode, you should file a bug report.

Comment: It's not in the output. It just shows "Test Failed" in grey box briefly like it shows "build success". I'm posting the output just in case if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is confused and reporting incorrect result.

I usually see this happen when it fails to clear a test failure from an old test run and decides that means all future test runs fail. Restarting Xcode should resolve this but probably does little to help your confidence in the tests you're writing.

You can also hit the opposite case where the test app crashes but Xcode reports success with 0 tests run.

Comment: I did restart Xcode as I read something similar on another thread, but the "test failed" message persists.